# onblur and onchange not working with input tag

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

After fighting this issue I discovered that the events `onblur` and `onchange` work as designed, but if your page only has ONE

```
<input type="text" onblur="loadXMLDoc()"> Change Content</input>
```

The events behave strangely in the different browsers. Trying to debug was wasted time, no errors! The issue was not having someplace for the focus/change to move to! I added

```
<input type="hidden"></input>
```

which ended this problem . What was disturbing to me was the fact that I Googled for hours trying to find an answer; I found a lot of people suggesting third party javascript libraries, some suggestions for interval timers and then those that added a `checkbox` or `submit` button. The answer was in reading the HTML DOM Event Object:Form Events: onblur - The event occurs when a form element loses focus. If you have no place to go how do you lose focus? RTM.

Comment: I believe that `loadXMLDoc` is internet-explorer only; could that be the problem?

Comment: Are you asking a question, or making an observation?

Answer (score 0):

`<input />` is right syntax not `<input></input>`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fN9Bc/)